# How to query for oneway flights using the Sabre Insta Flights Search REST API?

Tags: sabre

What query params do I need to pass to search for oneway flights only using the Sabre Insta Flights Search REST API?

I get an error from the service if I do not include a returndate param. If I do include a returndate, I get roundtrip flights in the result.

Thanks

Comment: What query parameters have you tried already? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Not every market has one-way flights loaded, specially in TEST. For instance, US does not currently support one-ways with InstaFlights.

As an example, the following RQ will yield resulsts in PROD, but not in TEST.

v1/shop/flights?origin=SYD&destination=BNE&departuredate=2016-12-18&pointofsalecountry=AU

Answer (score 0):

As an option to Instaflight, Sabre REST Bargain Finder Max is a Live Air Shopping API, that support both One-Way, Roundtrip and Multi Desti Flight Searches.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max