# Is the Sabre Advanced Calendar REST test api limited in its results?

Tags: sabre

The sample POST form on the [Sabre Dev Studio page](https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs) has a query setup for a round trip flight from DFW to LAX. You can submit the form and get results. However, if I change the airport from DFW to LAS then I don't get any results. I'm wondering if it's due to the test api having a limited amount of flight data loaded.

I was getting results for flights from LAS/OAK and BOS/LAS just a few days ago from my application I'm writing but now it's a 404 every time so I figured I'd try the sample page again.

**Update**: It looks like the 404's happen with one-way flights. My tests with round trips seem to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Sabre FAQ](https://developer.sabre.com/resources/FAQ) and this other [SO answer from Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001161/785809), I think this is the expected behavior on the TEST platform.

- test platform is limited to certain city pairs (Sabre FAQ)
- one way fares aren't loaded into the test platform (Bruno)
- my previously working requests were round trip and changed to one-way